# Calculating variance and standard deviation of continuous time series

Tags: time-series, variance, standard-deviation, continuous-data, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am trying to calculate the variance and standard deviation of an unevenly spaced continuous time series. Example data:

```
Time    Value
0       0
1000    1
2000    2
3000    3
5000    4
```

Where `Time` is the duration since the start of the time series. Duration between points is *not* guaranteed to be uniform.

`Value`s are continuous, e.g. the temperature measured throughout a day.

The arithmetic mean is weighted by `Time`, resulting in a mean for this example data being **`2.3`**

**How do I calculate the variance and standard deviation of `Value` in a continuous unevenly spaced time series?**